# Ajax works only on first id submitted (with php from db)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing an editor for navigation bar , to can reorder them , edit them and things like this. I made the part of sortable in ajax , but I got stuck at the submit function .

I want to change the name-viewed immediatly when i press the save button ,  and  it works!  , but only for my first placed navbar . 
At the second and third (in this example) , ajax won't work only If i replace them into the position one . 
maybe I can get some help from you guys , thanks in advance

Down here I will provide you my relevant codes for this part , and a screenshot
at the end

ajax code

```
$('.nav-form').submit(function(event){

        var navData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var navLabel = $('input[name=label]').val();
        var navID = $('input[name=id]').val();

        $.ajax({

            url: "ajax/nav-form.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: navData

        }).done(function(){

            $("#label_"+navID).html(navLabel);

        });
```

calling the alert method for navLabel and navID , i observed that they call only the first positioned item (even if i'm trying to edit the second or third navbar) , doesn't matter which one is it , if it's first placed

```
        alert(navLabel);
        alert(navID);
```

---

```
        event.preventDefault();

    });    



}); // END document.ready();
```

the relevant php/html codes

```
<ul id="sort-nav" class="list-group">

        <?php

        $q = "SELECT * FROM navigation ORDER BY position ASC";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

        while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>

            <li id="list_<?php echo $list['id']; ?>" class="list-group-item">
```

Form here i call the id in ajax

```
                <a id="label_<?php echo $list['id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $list['label']; ?>
                </a>
```

---

```
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_<?php echo $list['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></button>

                <div id="form_<?php echo $list['id']; ?>" class="collapse">


                    <form class="form-horizontal nav-form" action="index.php?page=navigation&id=<?php echo $list['id']; ?>" method="post" role="form">



this part of code I've erased because it's irelevant

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">

                        <input type="hidden" name="openedid" value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?>">

                    </form>
                </div>

            </li>
        <?php } ?>
```

[image]
hope I dind't gave you headaches with my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate the submit event so event listener isn't lost when the element gets moved

```
$(document).on('submit','.nav-form',function(event){
     // your same existing code
```

Comment: i just tryed it , but works like     $('.nav-form').submit(function(event){   , nothing changed

Comment: Hard to help much without being able to inspect this live in browser dev tools. Is there a demo link on web you can show this to me?

Comment: I'm in XHR to see ajax working , and no error have been throwed or something ... 

I think is a problem of logic in my syntax , but I'm newbie at ajax , that was the reason why I posted here...

Comment: If there is more than one form try changing `var navLabel = $('input[name=label]').val();` to `var navLabel = $(this).find('input[name=label]').val();` so values won't come from first form only. Do same for `navID `

Comment: Now I saw your later edit . Yes , it works now ! Thank you very much for your time ! Can I help you somehow ?